# How to search and replace in vertical selection in vim?

Tags: vim

I know I can do search and replace in horizontal selection with:

```
:'<,'>s/search/replace/g
```

But, I couldn't figure out how to do this in vertical selection. I tried the same method above by only having a vertical selection but, apparently, vim will search and replace to the entire line instead of just the selection.

Searched the internet to no avail. Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question directly, but the [`global`](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Power_of_g) command might be helpful in this case. You give it a regex for lines to match, and then you should be able to replace within the lines that match.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `\%V` in your regex, it will match position inside visual area:

```
\%V     Match inside the Visual area. This is a `/zero-width` match.
```

---

If you visual select a block:

```
search search search search
searc+---------------+earch
searc| search search |earch
searc| search search |earch
searc+---------------+earch
search search search search
```

After running this command:

```
:'<,'>s/\%Vsearch\%V/replace/g
```

It'll become:

```
search search search search
searc+---------------+earch
searc| replace replace |earch
searc| replace replace |earch
searc+---------------+earch
search search search search
```

Comment: You don't need the trailing `\%V` do you?

Comment: `:'<,'>s/\%Vsearch/replace/g` works as well.

Comment: @AndyRay The trailing `\%V` will exclude partial matches